# Editor with muti-line search and replace

Tags: windows, text-editors, regex

I am looking for text editor for Windows which is capable of performing search and replace operation of multi-line text block.

It should be able to run this operation on a folder or currently opened files.

Ideally it supports regular expressions, but it's not essential.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) for a while when I still had to do stuff on a Windows computer; it's got decent support for regular expressions. It's got an intuitive interface, and you won't have to memorize key combinations and shortcuts.

Comment: Tried notepad, works fine, only small issue is that multi-line text is not displayed correctly in little text area dedicated for search sentence. (weird characters where tab and \r\n should be).

Otherwise loving it! Especially search results grouping.

Comment: Hmm it's been a while since I used it, but I think there are options for how newlines, carriage returns, and tabs look. You might want to play around with the settings a bit. I used to switch between visible symbols for those and a more conventional appearance depending on what I was doing.

Comment: Notepad++ is also a ready-to-use package in the Ubuntu software manager. I'm using it for my multiline replacing and it works very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

Blocks are selected with v, Ctrl-V, or Shift-V (among other ways).  Once selected, substitute commands are run against the block by default.

Comment: Can you search for selected block in opened files in vim?

Comment: @Art yes, but i've no idea how offhand.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Basically, I select block of text with "V", and then I want to search for _selected text_ (not within it) in given file/folder. Can vim do that?

Comment: @Art - you wish to find a selected block of text within files in a folder, right ? Not within, but vim relies on several tools for that sort of thing (grep and the like), so start off that, and see what you need.

Comment: I can't think of a trivial way to do it, no.  You could write yourself a simple script that would take its input and search other files for it, and then use that script from within vim as a filter, maybe.  That's an odd request.

Comment: @Idigas: actually, Vim has a builtin grep: "`:vimgrep`", but I can't think of a way to get a visual block inside the pattern.

Comment: @wfaulk, thanks for your posts, but I think I'm gonna stick with np++.

Comment: Yes, Vim can definitely do this, but I don't think such a small feature is worth the learning curve of Vim.

Answer (score 2):

[emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Getting-Emacs.html)

Use `C-q C-j` to specify a newline in the pattern to match or replace with. Plain text and regexp are supported, either all at once or in query mode (get confirmation for each match).

The functions you want are

```
replace-string
query-replace-string
replace-regexp
query-replace-regexp
```

and they can all be invoked with `M-x <function name>`. Some have default bindings.

Use `C-h f <function-name>` to learn what binding is currently assigned to any function.

To select a block from the text to use

1. More the point to one end of the block. Hit `C-<space>`.
2. Move the point to the other end. Hit `C-w` which will yank the whole block then `C-y` to return the yanked block *or* invoke `copy-region-as-kill`.
3. `M-x <function>` then `C-y` to paste the block into the search space. Newlines are handled naturally.
4. proceed as normal.

Comment: You can also select a block of text by highlighting it with a mouse.  I know this sounds obvious, but some people do not know Emacs is a GUI application.

Answer (score 2):

**[EditPadPro](http://www.editpadpro.com/) for the win!**  It does everything you asked for:

1. Multi-line [search](http://www.editpadpro.com/search.html) and replace
2. Replace over all open files
3. Regex support

Actually I think the [free version](http://www.editpadpro.com/editpadlite.html) does all of that too.

It is seriously the best text editor I have ever used.  It has all the features you might need.  I typically find it goes beyond the call of duty.

Answer (score 1):

Not an text editor, but you should give [TextCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler) a shot. It is very lightweight and powerful tool to perform search and replace in files. A simple and good UI to put multiline text.

It allows Standard Search, Regular Expression, Fuzzy Search and Batch Commands.

Answer (score 0):

When I need multi-line search-replace I use Microsoft Word. I never use Microsoft Word as a text editor except when I need this feature. You can use ^p to search for linebreaks.

Typically I do this:

```
I edit a text file in my favorite text editor, but I need multi-line search-replace
Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C to select and copy all text editor
Start Microsoft Word
Ctrl-V
Search/Replace "First line^pSecond line" with "New first line^pNew second line"
Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C to select and copy all from Word
Switch back to text editor
Ctrl-V to paste newly fixed-up text
Continue editing document in my favorite editor
```

This works for me.