# Windows, selective text search and replace within files?

Tags: windows, search, text-editors, find-and-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editor with muti-line search and replace](https://superuser.com/questions/50938/editor-with-muti-line-search-and-replace)

I'm looking for (ideally free) software, which will perform selective search and replace on multiple text files.

So I want to search for a phrase and have it show all the lines which it occurs in all the files. I want to be able to select those lines and click replace.

Kind of like a preview before I commit the changes to the selected lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editor with muti-line search and replace](http://superuser.com/questions/50938/editor-with-muti-line-search-and-replace) also see [Search and replace tool that can handle multiple files and subfolders](http://superuser.com/questions/87544/search-and-replace-tool-that-can-handle-multiple-files-and-subfolders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: show all lines that will be changed

```
grep search-pattern file1 file2 file3
```

Step 2: go ahead

```
perl -p -i -e 's/search-pattern/replacement' file1 file2 file3
```

You could use awk instead of perl.

Grep and awk are in [GnuWIn32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). Perl can be obtained from [Strawberry](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/versions)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [SciTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scite)? It handles searching in multiple files quite gracefully and is completely free.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, SciTE looks pretty sweet... Word_SR is a nice one if you have MS Word and you want to search across anything Word can edit. They have one for Excel and PPT, too. It's free. http://www.funduc.com/word_sr.htm