# Tool to find & replace text with break lines

Tags: text-editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editor with muti-line search and replace](https://superuser.com/questions/50938/editor-with-muti-line-search-and-replace)

I'm editing multiple xml files in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), but it lack of possibility to find and replace text with break lines (ENTER-s). What tool / text-editor can do that ?

[image]

Comment: What text editor have you already tried? And what OS are you on, even?

Comment: Eclipse XML/Text editor

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant apart from the Eclipse editor. There are many text editors out there – so which alternative have you already looked at while researching for an answer to your question? And are you using Windows?